# Couchbase Lite - synchronising reference fields

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway, couchbase-ottoman

### **How does Couchbase Lite treat the [Ottoman's](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/node-ottoman) *ref* fields when synchronising with Couchbase Server using Sync Gateway?**

Trying to get myself familiar with Couchbase and after watching and reading about Couchbase Server & Couchbase Lite combination ([This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtBVULcqNYg), [this tutorial](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/node-ottoman/blob/master/docs/first-app.md), [and official docs](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/index.html)) I'm not understanding how Lite reflects the data models defined within the Server.

From what I see, Lite and Server are not much alike, even though both represent NoSQL databases. You define, store and work with data in - it seems - different ways. Nonetheless, the Sync Gateway is there to allow synchronising Lite with Server.

And here comes the main question - how do *ref* fields defined in Ottoman-based server ([check *Model References* here](http://ottomanjs.com/#toc9)) get reflected in Lite when synchronised using Sync Gateway?

Please correct me if I'm just getting the concept of refs or syncing completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document models of Couchbase Server and Couchbase Mobile are very similar. The main difference is that Couchbase Mobile reserves "_"-prefixed fields as metadata. Other than that, they both provide JSON documents named by string keys.

I don't know anything about Ottoman, but it sounds like 'ref' fields just contain a string that's the ID of the destination document. That works the same on both.

The thing I *do* know is that Ottoman uses a field name called `_type` in documents, which makes it incompatible with Couchbase Mobile. Sync Gateway will reject documents that contain properties prefixed with an underscore. I don't know if there's a way to tell Ottoman to use a different property name.